# Sample with replacement until x of any element is drawn

Tags: combinatorics

I'm wondering if there's a mathematical way to find out how to sample from a set with replacement until x of any element is found.

For example, if urn has ball {a,b,c}, I want mean of draws until I get 3 of a, 3 of b, or 3 of c.

Thinking about it a bit, one way is to brute force it for every n draws: so for example, for 3 draws, you can get aaa, bbb, or ccc as a success, with aba, abb, abc, etc as failures.

This seems inelegant. Is there a closed form formula for the distribution/mean?

Answer (score 1):

The event you have described follows negative binomial distribution.

Negative binomial distribution is the distribution of the number of trials to get certain number of successes.

Suppose, here we have 3 letters a, b and c and we want to get exactly 3 of a. Suppose, it is accomplished at rth trial. Then, at (r-1)th trial we will have 2 of a. The probability of that follows binomial distribution. The corresponding probability would be ${r-1}\choose{2}$ $(\frac{1}{3})^2 (\frac{2}{3})^{(r-3)}$ since $\frac{1}{3}$ is the probability of choosing a and $(\frac{2}{3})$ is the probability of choosing others at each trial.

Now, for the last trial, we have to multiply by the probability of choosing a  to get ${r-1}\choose{2}$ $(\frac{1}{3})^3 (\frac{2}{3})^{(r-3)}$

The expected number of trials would be $(\frac{r}{p})$ where r is the number of occurrence of a and p is the probability of choosing a in a trial.